# How to create a different class type depending on variable number of arguments

Tags: python

I have some python code which I would like to modularise:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
.
.
.
for s in list3:

    if object in list1:
        e = Class1(arg1, arg2, s)
    else:
        e = Class2(arg3, arg4, arg5, s)

    x(e)
    y(e)
    z(e)
```

I would like to replace the IF statement such that I can put the FOR loop and body within a method and pass in e, even though it can be one of two classes:

```
def my_method(self, list, e):

    for object in list:
        x(e)
        y(e)
        z(e)
```

and then simply call my_method() twice, once for list1 and again for list2:

```
# How/where do I "create" e1 and e2, given I need s, which is inside my_method()?
my_method(list1, e1)
my_method(list2, e2)
```

However, I am unsure how to create/pass in e, given it can represent two different class types, taking a different number of arguments and the last argument `s` is only known inside `my_method()`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a lambda

```
def my_method(self, list, callback):
    for object in list:
        e = callback(object)
        x(e)
        y(e)
        z(e)

my_method(list1, lambda s: Class1(arg1, arg2, s))
my_method(list2, lambda s: Class2(arg3, arg4, arg5, s))
```

Comment: Hi, what version of Python would I require to implement this?

Comment: I don't know, I thought it was pretty standard stuff.

Comment: It might be, I don't use Python very often

Comment: Everything in this answer will work in any remotely recent version of Python. The `lambda` keyword has been in the language since version 1.0, released in January 1994.

Comment: @user997112 I thought you were asking because it didn't work for you.